# How to count the number of words in a string?

Tags: c#, string, loops, count, cpu-word

I want to count the number of words in a string. 
Like if given a string:

```
string str = "Hello! How are you?";
```

thn the output will be:

```
Number of words in string “Hello! How are you?” is 4.
```

I'm using for loop, and these are my current codes.

```
    string wordCountStr = "";
    int noOfWords = 0;
    private void btn_Computate4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        wordCountStr = tb_Qns4Input.Text.ToString(); //tb_Qns4Input is a textbox.

        for (int i = 0; i< wordCountStr.Length; i++)
        {
            //I don't know how to code here.
        }

        lbl_ResultQns4.Text = "Number of words in string " + wordCountStr + " is " + noOfWords;
    }
```

Oh yes, I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 for my work. So the codes are under a button click event.

Addition:
What are the different methods to code using 'foreach', 'for loops', 'do/while' loops & 'while' loops?
I can only use these 4 loops to my work.

I have solved this question by using these codes:

```
    string wordCountStr = "";
    int noOfWords = 0;
    private void btn_Computate4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        wordCountStr = tb_Qns4Input.Text.ToString();
        foreach (string sentence in wordCountStr.TrimEnd('.').Split('.'))
        {
            noOfWords = sentence.Trim().Split(' ').Count();
        }


        lbl_ResultQns4.Text = "Number of words in ''" + wordCountStr + "'' is " + noOfWords;
    }
```

Comment: `str.Split(' ').Length`

Comment: Or str.Count(c => c == ' ') + 1 if you want to count only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming perfect input you can simply [split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) on the space and then get the `Length` of the resulting array.

```
int count = wordCountStr.Split(' ').Length;
```

Comment: I'm getting this error.
Error 1: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char[]'
Error 2:The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @TaeyeonUnnie. which error?

Comment: @TaeyeonUnnie. Change " " to ' ' I have update the answer

Comment: Okay! In the end I used foreach.
Will update my question with my working answers. :D Thanks for your help David.

Comment: @TaeyeonUnnie If he answered your question, you should accept his answer.